# Unwanted left hand margin appears

Tags: html, css

I'm a newbie to web-development. I am building a mock-up site for online food delivery. I am following the instructor line-by-line in both HTML and CSS.

I have placed some photos onto the site. There is an unwanted left-hand margin that appears. At first, I got rid of it by adjusting the CSS to include an astrix at the very start of the code:

```
*{
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

**This removes the unwanted margin.**

However, now the text and icon elements that were centered are no longer in the middle of the site. When I remove the * the text and icon elements return to the center, but when I include the * the text and icons move out of center alignment; a clear and unwanted trade-off!

Here is the CSS (of the element):

```
h1,
h2,
h3 {
    font-weight: 300;
    text-transform: uppercase;

}

h1{
    margin-top: 0;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 240%;
    word-spacing: 4px;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
}

h2{
font-size: 180%;
word-spacing: 2px;
text-align: center;
margin-bottom: 30px;
letter-spacing: 1px;
}

h3{
font-size: 110%;
margin-bottom: 15px;
}




h2::after {
    display: block;
    height: 2px;
    background-color: #e67e22;
    content: " ";
    width: 100px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    margin-top: 30px;
}

/*-------PARAGRAPHS--------*/
.long-copy{
    line-height: 145%;
    width:  70%;
    margin-left: 15%;
}

.box p {
   font-size: 90%;
line-height: 145%;
```

}

```
/*-------ICONS------------*/
.icon-big{
    font-size: 350%;
    display: block;
    color: #e67e22;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}
```

How do I produce a site that has NO left margin AND the text and icon elements in the center?

**HTML:**

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="vendors/CSS/normalize.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Vendors/CSS/Grid.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="vendors/CSS/ionicons.min.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="resources/CSS/style.css">
        <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com">
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Lato:ital,wght@0,100;0,300;0,400;1,300&display=swap" rel="stylesheet"> 
        <title> Omifood</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <header>
            <nav>
                <div class="row">
                    <img src="Resources/Images/logo-white.png" alt="Omnifood logo" class="logo">
                    <ul class="main-nav">
                        <li><a href="#">Food Delivery</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">How it Works</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Our Cities</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Sign up</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>


            </nav>
            <div class="hero-text-box">
                <h1>Goodbye junk food. <br> Hello super healthy meals</h1>
                <a class="btn btn-full" href="#">I'm hungry</a>
                <a class="btn btn-ghost" href="#">Show me more</a>
            </div>

        </header>

        <section class="section-features">
            <div class="row">
                <h2>Get Food Fast &mdash; not Fast Food</h2>
                <p class="long-copy">
                    Hello, we’re Omnifood, your new premium food delivery service. We know you’re always busy. No time for cooking. So let us take care of that, we’re really good at it, we promise!
                </p>
            </div>

            <div class="row">
                <div class="col span-1-of-4 box">
                    <i class="ion-ios-infinite-outline icon-big"></i>
                    <h3>Up to 365 days/year</h3>
                    <p>
                        Never cook again! We really mean that. Our subscription plans include up to 365 days/year coverage. You can also choose to order more flexibly if that's your style.
                    </p>
                </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col span-1-of-4 box">
                    <i class="ion-ios-stopwatch-outline icon-big"></i>
                    <h3>Ready in 20 Minutes</h3>
                    <p>
                        You're only twenty minutes away from your delicious and super healthy meals delivered right to your home. We work with the best chefs in each town to ensure that you're 100% happy.
                    </p>
                </div>    
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col span-1-of-4 box">
                    <i class="ion-ios-nutrition-outline icon-big"></i>
                        <h3>100% Organic</h3>
                        <p>
                        All our vegetables are fresh, organic and local. Animals are raised without added hormones or antibiotics. Good for your health, the environment, and it also tastes better!
                        </p>
                    </div>       
             <div class="row">
                <div class="col span-1-of-4 box">
                    <i class="ion-ios-cart-outline icon-big"></i>
                        <h3>Order Anything</h3>
                        <p>
                        We don't limit your creativity, which means you can order whatever you feel like. You can also choose from our menu containing over 100 delicious meals. It's up to you!
                        </p>
                    </div> 
                </div>
        </section>

        <section class="section-meals">
            <ul class="meals-showcase">
                <li>
                    <figure class="meal-photo">
                        <img src="resources/Images/1.jpg" alt="Korean bibimap with egg and vegtables">
                    </figure>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <figure class="meal-photo">
                        <img src="resources/Images/2.jpg" alt="Simple Italian Pizza with Cherry Tomatoes">
                    </figure>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <figure class="meal-photo">
                        <img src="resources/Images/3.jpg" alt="Chicken breast steak with vegtables">
                    </figure>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <figure class="meal-photo">
                        <img src="resources/Images/4.jpg" alt="Autumn pumpkin soup">
                    </figure>
                </li>
            </ul>
            <ul class="meals-showcase">
                <li>
                    <figure class="meal-photo">
                        <img src="resources/Images/5.jpg" alt="Paleo beef steak with vegtables">
                    </figure>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <figure class="meal-photo">
                        <img src="resources/Images/6.jpg" alt="Healthy baguette with egg and vegetables">
                    </figure>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <figure class="meal-photo">
                        <img src="resources/Images/7.jpg" alt="Burger with cheddar and bacon">
                    </figure>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <figure class="meal-photo">
                        <img src="resources/Images/8.jpg" alt="Granola with cherries and strawberries">
                    </figure>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </section>


             

    </body>


</html>
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: can you create an example with youre code so we can test it  i see margin-left:15%;?

Comment: Hey man, thanks for the response,  here is the URL:

file:///Users/iyobosa/OneDrive/Web%20Development/Omifood/index.html

Have a look at the CSS with inspect element and see. Let me know if this helps.

Comment: Its a file in your local, We cant get access to it.Can you include HTML code as well ?

Comment: Thought so, sorry about that. I'll paste the HTML into the thread.

Comment: @Bosa_89  have you solved it

Comment: If an answer helped you, then please mark it as correct.

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of problems with your code. If you look at this example, that is how I would fix them. Compare them to your code and possibly you will see what is happening as `flex` is being used to position elements.

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

header {
  width: 100%;
  flex-direction: column;
  display: flex;
}

nav {
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.hero-text-box {
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  text-align: center;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
}

.flex-row {
  display: flex;
}

.btn {
  margin: 0 5px;
}

h1,
h2,
h3 {
  font-weight: 300;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

h1 {
  margin-top: 0;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  font-size: 240%;
  word-spacing: 4px;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
}

h2 {
  font-size: 180%;
  word-spacing: 2px;
  text-align: center;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
}

h3 {
  font-size: 110%;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
}

h2::after {
  display: block;
  height: 2px;
  background-color: #e67e22;
  content: " ";
  width: 100px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  margin-top: 30px;
}


/*-------PARAGRAPHS--------*/

.long-copy {
  line-height: 145%;
  width: 70%;
  margin-left: 15%;
}

.box p {
  font-size: 90%;
  line-height: 145%;
}


/*-------ICONS------------*/

.icon-big {
  font-size: 350%;
  display: block;
  color: #e67e22;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="vendors/CSS/normalize.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Vendors/CSS/Grid.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="vendors/CSS/ionicons.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="resources/CSS/style.css">
  <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Lato:ital,wght@0,100;0,300;0,400;1,300&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
  <title>Omifood</title>
</head>

<body>
  <header>
    <nav>
      <img src="Resources/Images/logo-white.png" alt="Omnifood logo" class="logo">
      <a href="#">Food Delivery</a>
      <a href="#">How it Works</a>
      <a href="#">Our Cities</a>
      <a href="#">Sign up</a>
    </nav>
    <div class="hero-text-box">
      <h1>Goodbye junk food. <br> Hello super healthy meals</h1>
      <div class="flex-row">
        <a class="btn btn-full" href="#">I'm hungry</a> 
        <a class="btn btn-ghost" href="#">Show me more</a>
      </div>
    </div>

  </header>
```

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, I will compare and contrast and respond with my findings. Thanks for the help!